# How to make DOM assertions using Angular Material's component harnesses?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, angular-material

I'm trying to understand how to properly use [Angular's Component Harnesses](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/guides/using-component-harnesses.md) in my tests. I'm able to manipulate components using the harness, but I don't understand how to make assertions about their DOM properties.

Partial example to save space:

```js
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { HarnessLoader } from '@angular/cdk/testing';
import { MatButtonToggleHarness } from '@angular/material/button-toggle/testing';
import { MatButtonToggleModule} from "@angular/material/button-toggle";

...

const toggleOn = await loader.getHarness(MatButtonToggleHarness.with({text: 'ON'}));
expect(await toggleOn.host()).toBeVisible();
```

This throws an error:

`received value must be an HTMLElement or an SVGElement.`

Is there some way to get at the native `HTMLElement`? Or what am I doing wrong here? How are we intended to make assertions against components wrapped in these test harnesses?

Comment: I think that error is because toggleOn.host() returns a promise that resolves to an instance of TestElement (provided by @angular/cdk/testing), not the actual native HTMLElement. To make DOM assertions, you could try using the methods and properties from TestElement.

Comment: Yes, that sounds plausible, but the `TestElement` methods are quite limited, there's a list here: https://dev.to/this-is-angular/create-a-component-harness-for-your-tests-with-angular-cdk-46bg What could I use to test for visibility? Maybe `getCssValue`?